# call another component layout in custom component

Tags: templates, layout, joomla, joomla2.5

I have 4 JavaScript tabs like friends,video,user management and list of product. Now i want to load user profile layout in user management tab. default joomla user profile layout.
Is this possible

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible. There are some extensions that could help you find out how to do it, one of them is:

[Nonumber Components Anywhere](http://www.nonumber.nl/extensions/componentsanywhere)